# Rigorous definition of iteration of logarithm

Tags: definition, recursion, function-and-relation-composition

We usually use the recursion theorem to define rigorously the iterated (by composition) $f^n$ of a function, 
I want to give a rigorous definition of $\log^{n}x= \log(log^{n-1}x)$ (here there is a composition not power). In this case not for all $n$ the $\log$ exists (the domain of $\log^n$ depends on $n$). The problem is how to use [the recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem) or is there a way to give a formal definition?

We have the same question when we define the family of operators $D^n$ where $D$ is the derivative operator.

Comment: I guess you mean $\log^{n}x= \log(\log^{n-1}(x))?$ BTW: Most people treat $\log^n(x)$ as $(\log x )^n,$ the same as in $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1.$

Comment: Yes I mean composition, thanks.

Comment: I mean that in your definition another $\log$ is missing, $\log^n = \log^{n-1}$ is makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed it.

Comment: You can prove your claim using induction. I.e. you want to prove for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that there exists a unique function $f_n$ such that it satisfies the recursion relation on the domains given in the answer of gandalf61.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* use an extended definition of $\log$ as follows:

$$\log_{\#}:\Bbb R\cup\{\#\}\to \Bbb R\cup\{\#\},\quad \log_{\#}(x)=\begin{cases} \log(x), &\text{for $x>0$}\\ \#,&\text{for $x\le 0$ or $x=\#$}\end{cases}.$$

The function $\log_{\#}$ basically behaves like $\log$, but has matching domain and co-domain, and returns a placeholder value $\#$ (use here whatever you want) where $\log(x)$ would not be defined otherwise. There is no problem in applying the **Recursion Theorem** (see the version in the post of @Joe) to this extended function. For each fixed $a\in\Bbb R$ you then obtain the existence of a function

$$f_a(n)=\log_{\#}^n(a).$$

Every such function will return constantly $\#$ after some finite $n\in\Bbb N$. You can then interpret this as a restriction of the domain. E.g. you can define

$$D_a:=\{n\in\Bbb N\mid f_a(x) \not=\#\}$$

as the "domain" of the recursively defined functions $f_a(n)$. E.g. $D_a=\{0\}$ for $a\le 0$ or $D_a=\{0,1\}$ for $a\in(0,1]$.

---

**Update**

Here is another way to approach your problem, maybe this is more satisfying to you. Consider the set

$$\mathcal F:=\{\text{$f$ function} \mid \exists\alpha\in\Bbb R:\mathrm{dom}(f)=(\alpha,\infty)\}.$$

This set contains all the "interesting" functions, especially it containes $\log$ and all the iterates $\log^n$ (that we still have to define).

We define a function $h:\mathcal F\to\mathcal F$ as follows: given $f\in\mathcal F$ with $\mathrm{dom}(f)=(\alpha,\infty)$, then

$$h(f)= f\circ\log|_{\smash{(e^\alpha,\infty)}}.$$

Here, $\log|_{\smash{(e^\alpha,\infty)}}$ denotes the restriction of $\log$ to the domain $(e^\alpha,\infty)$. Note that the concatenation of $f$ with the restricted $\log$ is valid because for $x\in(e^\alpha,\infty)$ we have $\log(x)\in(\alpha,\infty)=\mathrm{dom}(f)$. Further, $h(f)$ is a function with domain $(e^\alpha,\infty)$, and therefore $h(f)\in\mathcal F$.

Now, by the **Recursion Theorem** there is a unique function $H:\Bbb N\to\mathcal F$ with

$$H(1)=\log,\qquad H(n+1)=h(H(n)).$$

Finally, we can define $\log^n:=H(n)$.

Comment: If I'm not wrong we can set $dom(log^n):=\{x \in\Bbb R \mid log_{\#}^{n}(x) \not=\#  \}$ and $log^n(x)=log_{\#}^{n}(x) $

Comment: Maybe we can use directly the recursion for $log$ if we accept composition of functions in every case also when the composed function should have a empty domain. What do you think?

Comment: @asv The Recursion Theorem is needed to define $\log^n(x)$ for fixed $x$ but *all* $n$ at once. You seem to want to define $\log^n(x)$ for fixed $n$ but *all* $x$ at once, for which the theorem is not really needed, but induction suffices as in gandalf's post. However, you can do it as described in your first comment. If you want me to go into detail here, I can extend my post when I find time. Just say so.

To your second comment: if I understand you correctly, this would need another form of the Recursion Theorem. So you would have to prove it your own instead of just naming it.

Comment: Yes I want to define sequence of functions $f^{\circ n}$. It would be interesting to have a way to define iterated function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function in rigorous way also with  f:X→Y. I think we can do it if we use the same recurion theorem and if we define composition of functions in every case. Of course after applied the recursion theorem we must proof that $dom(f^{\circ n})$ for all $n$ is not empty if we want a infinte family of not empty functions.

Comment: @asv I have a hard time to fully grasp what kind of result you expect. I need several clarifications: 1. You seem to want to use the Recursion Theorem *very badly*. Why, if it might not be necessary? 2. Might it be that you actually want to show the existence of the function $f$ that for every $n\in\Bbb N$ outputs the function $\log^n$? Because if you just want the existence of $\log^n$ you *do not need the recursion theorem* (see question 1). [continue ...]

Comment: @asv  [...] 3. You say you want to define $\log^n$ rigorously. But what does this mean for you? You want to show the existence? You seem to use ZFC set theory in the background, in which a function is a set of ordered pairs and does not carry any extra information about domain and codomain. Hence we do not need to define $\mathrm{dom}(\log^n)$ explicitely, because it just falls off after we defined $\log^n$. 4. You say you want to define iterated function rigorously. What do you mean with that? What is wrong with the definition by usual composition.

Comment: @asv I made an edit to the post. This is my new guess for what might be your intention. If this is still unsatisfying, please let me know and answer my questions from above to help me to help you.

Comment: There's no more the definition of the set F. Can you rewrite it?

Comment: @asv Are you sure? I can still see it. Maybe reload the page. Had the same problem recently with another post here. Otherwise, it is $$\mathcal F:=\{\text{$f$ function} \mid \exists\alpha\in\Bbb R:\mathrm{dom}(f)=(\alpha,\infty)\}.$$
Or in plain text: F = { f function | dom(f) = (a,infinity) for some real number a }.

Comment: I tried but I can't see it neither in your last comment. You can try to change some letters maybe some problem with latex.

Comment: @asv Apparently MathJax rendering [doesn't work well](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30861/invisible-latex-code) lately with some renderers in some browsers. [Changing the renderer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30859/how-do-i-change-math-renderer-for-mathjax) often helps.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the iterated logarithm $\log^n$ by:

$\log^1(x) = \log(x)$

$\log^n(x) = \log(\log^{n-1}(x)) \quad n \ge 2$

Then as functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\log^1$ has domain $(0, \infty)$; $\log^2$ has domain $(1, \infty)$; $\log^3$ has domain $(e, \infty)$; $\log^4$ has domain $(e^e, \infty)$. Using the tetration notation $^na$, the domain of $\log^n$ is $^{n-2}e$. All of the iterations have range $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: How you use the recursion theorem? When you say 'etc.' is not a rigorous way if I'm not wrong. Using this (if it is useful): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem

Who is f, X, a, and F?

Comment: The recursion theorem is an existence theorem - it simply guarantees that a recursive definition like this results in an actual function (or, more precisely, a countably infinite sequence of functions). The domain of $\log^n$ can be expressed more formally using tetration notation - I have edited my answer to include this.

Comment: I don't see who is $f$ in this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem.

$f$ is not $log$ maybe $f$ is the operator $f(g)=log \circ g$ ?

Comment: I like your idea but the domains are calculated supposing we already have the functions $log^n$ that we want to define, then at rigours it is not a proof but a justification for the chosen domains which are introduced by hand. Instead in Winter answer the domains can be proved after. There's nothing wrong is only a taste question.

Answer (score 1):

gandalf61 Does a **great** job of properly defining the iterated logarithm, but asv is hung up on the recursion theorem. Notice that the recursion theorem is NOT satisfied by the iterated logarithm.

> **The Recursion Theorem**: Given a set $X$, and elment $a \in X$, and a function $f:X\rightarrow X$, there exists a unique $F: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow X$ such that $F(0)=a$ and $F(n+1) = f(F(n))$

If we were to try and define the iterated logarithm through the recursion theorem, we run into an immediate problem. We want to set $f = \log$, but notice that $\log : \mathbb{R}_{>0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. In particular, for any set $S \subset\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, there is some $x \in S$ such that $\log(x) \not \in S$. Thus, there is no way to set the domain and codomain of $\log$ to be the same set. This goes against the requirement of the recusion theorem that the function $f$ has the same domain and codomain.

gandalf61's definition also points out this problem: for each iteration of the iterated logarithm, you must change the domain of the function. See their answer for the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed not possible to apply the recursive function theorem to the logarithm function. Instead, you can use the function $\log ex$ ($=\log x+1$).

But the classical *iterated logarithm*, denoted as $\log^*(x)$ is defined as the number of times you can iterate the logarithm from a starting $x$ as long as the result exceeds $1$.

Comment: I changed the title of the post in "Rigorous definition of iteration of logarithm".